# registerForActivityResult won't seem to import Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, registerforactivityresult

Im trying to use the function registerForActivityResult in my android project made in android studio. But when I write "registerForActivityResult" to use the function all that is showing is create function.
I thought registerForActivityResult was a remade function in Android an I don't know what to do to make it work.
If any of you kind souls could help me I would deeply appreciate it, I can always gather more information if needed!

**Update**
Im currently using the guide provided in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XV-IYHYX__4&ab_channel=BrandanJones) video. I am using android.activity.1.3.1 and the code that isn't working is this:  `private val signInLauncher = registerForActivityResult (         FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract()     ) {         res -> this.signInResult(res)     }`

Comment: Post the code that isn't working. (Also what version of `androidx.activity` are you using?)

Comment: Im currently using the guide provided in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XV-IYHYX__4&ab_channel=BrandanJones) video. I am using `android.activity.1.3.1` and the code that isn't working is this: 
`private val signInLauncher = registerForActivityResult (
        FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract()
    ) {
        res -> this.signInResult(res)
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try manually casting to `ComponentActivity`.

I've ended up creating an extension for this function:

```
fun <I, O> Activity.registerForActivityResult(
    contract: ActivityResultContract<I, O>,
    callback: ActivityResultCallback<O>
) = (this as ComponentActivity).registerForActivityResult(contract, callback)
```

It seems there is an open bug for AndroidStudio:  [Bug: unable to find registerForActivityResult on large project despite having the needed dependencies](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178403178)

For using this, in your `Activity` when you need to request multiple permissions for example you could do something like this:

```
registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
) { result ->
    // Do something with the result 
}
```

Comment: Exactly how do you use this function, I am pretty new to both Kotlin and Jetpack Compose, so sorry if I seem confused

Comment: I've updated the answer to include an usage example.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `rememberLauncherForActivityResult` if your are using compose?

```
val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.WhatEverYoutWant) {...}
```